# Which slots to use for laptop RAM?

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop

I have two 4GB memory sticks in my Lenovo w520 laptop.  The only difference between them is the manufacturer. One is Transcend 2rx8, another one is Samsung 1rx8.

I installed them separately thinking it would cause incompatibility, 1 of them is in slot 1 and another in slot 3.

Should I put them in pairs?

Comment: Please specify the exact models of your RAM. Mounting them in separate banks will not solve the compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your specs against Lenovo's page.

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd015362

Special attention to this note:

- If your computer is a dual-core processor model it will have two Dummy DIMM cards preinstalled in the topside and underside of your computer. Do not replace the Dummy DIMM cards with SO-DIMMs
- Quad-core models utilize all four slots.

Answer (score 0):

If it works, just keep them the way they are.

If you want to experiment, you can try putting them on the same banks to see if they are compatible, but be prepared to revert if you get inadvertent crashes.

There are far more to RAM than just the specs.  Even RAM of a different build but with the same specs can have ever so slight differences to potentially cause problems.  I tend to buy and install RAM in pairs to avoid the hassle of dealing with the problems, but if you are on a budget, there is no harm in trying.